# Android Could not find class, Nested jars issues?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I have two projects, the first is a library (Marked as "isLibrary" in the eclipse properties -> android settings) and the second is an android application.  The android application uses the library and everything works ok.

I am now trying to include a jar file in the library and access it's functionality in a class (we will call it ClassA) also found again in the library.  Now in the android application I create a new instance of the ClassA and tell it to do some stuff that will use functions provided by the jar I added in the library.  I end up with this error:

```
"Android could no find class 'com.blah.blah.blah' etc."
```

I checked the .classpath in the library and it is exporting the jar properly.  What could I be missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that while you can use any "lib" folder you want in eclipse, and add it to the classpath, I'm pretty sure for Android to package things correctly the jar should be placed in a folder called `libs`.

Comment: Ya, I actually already changed the lib folder to libs, however it is still not working.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I've done this several times, and with the exception of needing to put the library in the libs folder, i've never seen an issue.  Perhaps try rebuilding both the library and other project and see if that helps.